# How to create first project in bitbucket using ssh key?

Tags: bitbucket, version

I have tired to create my first project on bitbuck bucket with ssh key but it says that after cloning permission denied. 
Please help me anyone to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you please tell us the steps you used?

Comment: It's working fine now !! Thanks